# C++ Quantlib Vanilla Swap: setting future fixing dates and gearing for floating leg

Tags: c++, quantlib

Is it possible for user to change the future fixing dates and gearing of the floating leg in Quantlib?

First, when Quantlib calculate the NPV for floating leg, it will go into couponpricer.hpp to call inline function `BlackIborCouponPricer::swapletPrice()`. Inside this function, there is a parameter called `gearing_`. This parameter is automatically setting to 1 in my case. If I need to change this to other value, say 0.8, where shall I make this change?

Second, all my future fixing dates are the same as the date vector generated in floating leg schedule. i.e. fixing dates are the same as accrual period starting dates. Is it possible to change these fixing dates to be different from the accrual period starting dates, say 2 business days before accrual starting dates subject to normal business day convention adjustment? Alternatively, is it possible for me to pass a date vector to store these fixing dates?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`VanillaSwap` doesn't take gearings as a constructor argument (I guess the idea was to keep it simple). Instead, you can create the fixed and floating legs separately using the `FixedLeg` and `IborLeg` classes and pass them to  a `Swap` instance.  You can see an example of that in `SwapTest::testInArrears()`, in the `test-suite/swap.cpp` file.

As for the fixing dates: when you build the `IborIndex` instance to be passed to `IborLeg`, you can pass a number of fixing days to its constructor.  If you're using the available indexes such as `Euribor` or `USDLibor`, though, they already use 2 fixing days (as well as the correct calendar and business-day convention).

Comment: a further question on fixing date: I set the `IborIndex` as `USDLibor` with 3m tenor. I generate the schedules for both fixed leg and float leg with start date(15,4,2016) and end date(18,4,2017) with tenor 12m and 3m, respectively. The schedules generated are as expected. However, when I pass them to price a swap, Quantlib complains that 'cannot calculate forward rate between April 18th, 2017 and April 18th, 2017:non positive time (0) using Actual/360 daycounter'. If I change the starting date to (18,4,2016). This issue solved.

Comment: Are the schedules as expected, or is there a duplicated date at the end?

Comment: Also, this should probably be a different question, so that it's easier to find it if someone else runs into the same problem.

Comment: After debugging into the source code, I know how this error generated. It does come from the schedule generation. Since Quantlib can only take either forward/backward generation as STUB, so the last two schedule dates are  Date(15,4,2017), Date(18,4,2017). This causes class IborCoupon::IborCoupon generate the same fixingValueDate_ and fixingEndDate_ for last period. In practice, we normally have 4 different STUB: front short, front long, back short and back long. In this case, if I use back long, the last period in shcedule will be  Date(15,1,2017) to Date(18,4,2017).

Comment: Agree. It really should be a separate question.